# C programming expression tree to postfix to solution using lines read from a file

Tags: c, expression-trees, infix-notation, postfix-notation

I am terribly new at C programming. 
I have stumbled upon a few answers. Some using the old syntax.

The problem is I have to create a program the will read a text file and use the read postfix lines to convert to an infix equation.

The text file would be something like this:

```
6            #this is the number ofcontainters
1 + 3 4      # it's no_operation_if op!=v then read value of nos mention
2 + 5 6 
3 v 2.1 
4 v 2.4
5 v 3.5 
6 v 1.5
```

The C file will be read in the Ubuntu terminal where the text file is the only input and the output is the infix form.

A few suggestion as to how I will accomplish this using **struct, arrays, and unions.**
We were already given a format of creating struct opnode, vnode, and uniting them.
The array part I'm clueless how to transfer from reading to the array itself.
C is so weird compared to java as of this moment.

[EDIT]

Sorry I forgot to mention that this is homework... no longer postfix to infix. It's postfix to solve the equation.

Without prior knowledge of syntax and used to object oriented programming I don't know how to edit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAXLENGTH 512

/* Codes by DocM
 * struct opnode, vnode, union
 */

struct opnode{
char operator
int loperand;
int roperand;
};
struct vnode {
char letterv;
double value;
};
union {
struct opnode op;
struct vnode val;
} nodes[100];

/*node[2].op.loperand
 *node[6].val.value
 */
```

/* This reads text file string input in terminal
 * Then commands the text file be read
 * etc.
 * and everything else actually
 */

```
int main()
{
char text[MAXLENGTH];
fputs("enter some text: ", stdout);
fflush(stdout);

int i = 0;
int f = 0;

if ( fgets(text, sizeof text, stdin) != NULL )
{
    FILE *fn;
    fn = fopen(text, "r");
}

    /* The code below should be the body of the program
 * Where everything happens.
 */


fscanf (text, "%d", &i);
int node[i];

for(int j = 0; j<i;j++)
{
    int count = 0;
    char opt[MAXLENGTH];
    fscanf(text,"%d %c", &count, &opt);
    if(opt == -,+,*,)
    {
        fscanf(text,"%d %d", &node[j].op.loperand,&node[j].op.roperand);
        node[j].op,operator = opt;
    }
    else
    {
        fscanf(text, "%lf", &node[j].val.value);
    }
    fscanf(text,"%lf",&f);
}
evaluate(1);
return 0;
}

/* Code (c) ADizon below
 *
 */

double evaluate(int i)
{
if(nodes[i].op.operator == '+' | '*' | '/' | '-')
{
    if (nodes[i].op.operator == '+')
    return evaluate(nodes, nodes[i].op.loperator) + evaluate(nodes[i].op.roperator);
    if (nodes[i].op.operator == '*')
    return evaluate(nodes, nodes[i].op.loperator) * evaluate(nodes[i].op.roperator);
    if (nodes[i].op.operator == '/')
    return evaluate(nodes, nodes[i].op.loperator) / evaluate(nodes[i].op.roperator);
    if (nodes[i].op.operator == '-')
    return evaluate(nodes, nodes[i].op.loperator) - evaluate(nodes[i].op.roperator);
}
else
{
    printf nodes[i].val.value;
    return nodes[i].val.value;
}

}
```

Comment: Is this homework? It should be tagged as such, in that case.

Comment: Technically, since the operations come before the values, that's not postfix, it's prefix aka Polish notation.

Comment: Why would you want to use a struct, array, or union for that? This does look like homework. Some dumb teacher coming up with a problem then forcing you to use unnecessary programming constructs just to show you know how to use them. Reminds me of an interview question where the interviewer wanted me to use a for loop but I came up with a highly optimised solution using a while loop and some bitmasks. After I had answered he asked "Do you know how to use a for loop? How would you solve this using a for loop?" Same deal here. This is homework isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the basic algorithm should be:

- Read the count for number of lines (not sure why this is necessary, would be easier to just keep reading for as long as there is indata provided, but whatever)
- For each expected line:

  - Parse out the expected four sub-strings
  - Ignore the first, which seems to be a pointless linenumber
  - Print out the substrings in a shuffled order to create the "infix" look
- Be done

I don't understand the part about the "v" operator, maybe you should clarify that part.

This seems a bit too much like homework for us to just blindly post code ... You need to show your own attempt first, at least.

Comment: I edited with a code. I had just used scanf. Several errors with actual syntax in compilation. Declaration? Instantiation?